# How to Reverse Sort a nested list starting with Uppercase entries?

Tags: python, list, sorting, case

List `r`:

```
r= [['Paris', 10], ['amsterdam', 5], ['London', 18], ['london', 15], ['Berlin', 2], ['Stockholm', 4], ['oslo', 14], ['helsinki', 16], ['Zurich', 17]]
```

If I do a reverse sort:

```
sorted(r, reverse=True)

[['oslo', 14], ['london', 15], ['helsinki', 16], ['amsterdam', 5], ['Zurich', 17], ['Stockholm', 4], ['Paris', 10], ['London', 18], ['Berlin', 2]]
```

What I want is to start with Upper case elements and than the lower case elements.

```
[ ['Zurich', 17], ['Stockholm', 4], ['Paris', 10], ['London', 18], ['Berlin', 2], ['oslo', 14], ['london', 15], ['helsinki', 16], ['amsterdam', 5]]
```

Is there an easy way in Python3 to sort the list as I want?

Comment: I think the behaviour is because of the ASCII values of the capital and small letters.

Comment: First sort by name, then by "casing": `r.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]); r.sort(key=lambda x: x[0].islower())`. This works because `list.sort` uses a stable sorting algorithm (i.e. it preserves the relative order of equal elements). `list.sort` is also an adaptive sort, which means it can take O(n) time if the input is partially sorted and after the first sort the input is very well partially sorted according to the key `x[0][0].islower()`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Everything is possible with a custom `key` function:

```
>> sorted(r, key=lambda e: (not e[0].islower(), e[0]), reverse=True)
[['Zurich', 17], ['Stockholm', 4], ['Paris', 10], ['London', 18], ['Berlin', 2],
 ['oslo', 14], ['london', 15], ['helsinki', 16], ['amsterdam', 5]]
```

Comment: Great solution. Thanks. It also works the other way around `sorted(r, key=lambda e: (not e[0].islower(), e[0]))` (=default case sort but starting with lowercase entries).